# Multiple colors in TextField not working for all words in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm making an IDE for Kotlin, I want to be able to color the keywords with blue color but it doesn't filter the second or the third ... etc from the beginning as follows:

[image]

I tried different regex patterns but didn't get what I desired.

Here is my function :

```
fun buildAnnotatedStringWithColors(code: String): AnnotatedString {
    val pattern = "[ \\t]"
    val words: List<String> = code.split(pattern.toRegex())
    val builder = AnnotatedString.Builder()
    for (word in words) {
        when (word) {
            in keywordList -> {
                builder.withStyle(
                    style = SpanStyle(
                        color = funKeyWords,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                    )
                ) {
                    append("$word ")
                }
            }
            else -> {
                builder.withStyle(
                    style = SpanStyle(
                        color = PrimaryColor,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                    )
                ) {
                    append("$word ")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return builder.toAnnotatedString()
}
```

I want to be able to have white spaces, and new lines, and be colored at the same time so [\\s] doesn't work for me.

Comment: What's your expected output? that each `val` is blue? Or the first `val` on each line? Or what exactly? And personally I don't have any experience making syntax highlighting, but I feel like this is the wrong approach anyway. Code can become quite complex which can't be simply handled with some regex. You probably need to build some kind of grammar parser

Comment: @Ivo Beckers Yes each val is blue. 
Grammar parser for only highlighting the keywords?

Comment: so what about `val pattern = "[\\s]"` ?

Comment: @IvoBeckers it works but how to decide what to append after the word? whether to add \n or a space.

Comment: ah yeah, good question. I'm not sure how to handle that

Comment: @IvoBeckers Thank you for your time :), btw I'm using jdoodle api so I don't have to handle the syntax grammar myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this might work

```
fun buildAnnotatedStringWithColors(code: String): AnnotatedString {
    val pattern = "(?<=[\\s])"
    val words: List<String> = code.split(pattern.toRegex())
    val builder = AnnotatedString.Builder()
    for (word in words) {
        when (word.trim()) {
            in keywordList -> {
                builder.withStyle(
                    style = SpanStyle(
                        color = funKeyWords,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                    )
                ) {
                    append(word)
                }
            }
            else -> {
                builder.withStyle(
                    style = SpanStyle(
                        color = PrimaryColor,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                    )
                ) {
                    append(word)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return builder.toAnnotatedString()
}
```